# Using sudo with `virt-install` returns an error Permission denied on qcow2 disk

Tags: qemu, kvm, libvirt, virsh

I created a `qcow2` disk using `qemu-img`, i.e.:

```bash
qemu-img create -f qcow2 -F qcow2 -b /home/user/Downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img ./ex-os.img 10G
```

Next I tried to create a VM using `virt-install` in the following way:

```bash
virt-install --name os-test \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk path=ex-os.img,device=disk \
--import \
--os-variant ubuntu20.04 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial
```

This works, and installation begins however when I try to do the same using `sudo` priveleges, it fails.

```bash
sudo virt-install --name os-test \
--memory 2048 \
--vcpus 2 \
--disk path=ex-os.img,device=disk \
--import \
--os-variant ubuntu20.04 \
--graphics none \
--console pty,target_type=serial

[sudo] password for user:

Starting install...
ERROR    internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2024-01-14T05:07:35.714023Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/home/user/Downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img","node-name":"libvirt-2-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}: Could not open '/home/user/Downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img': Permission denied
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start os-test
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

I have tried giving `777` permission to the img itself, but I still get `Permission Denied`

```bash
chmod 777 /home/user/Downloads/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Why do you want to run `virt-install` with root privileges? I don't think it is wise to run `qemu` as root user.

Comment: I am just trying to understand why the `Permission Denied`. As we know root user must have access to everything, yet this occurs.

Comment: No, it's not true that root user has access to everything. There is a thing called `groups` in Linux, I suggest you should read about it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, but on my system to run as `sudo` means to run as `root`, so it has access to all files and directories on my system regardless of the permissions set on them.

I believe in this case also root has access to the file. Here is something I [found](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/does-root-belong-to-all-groups-permissions-question-637977/)

Comment: I think virt-install should normally not require sudo, but anyway I get a very similar error on a newly installed Ubuntu 22.04. As if it's not fully operational on a newly installed system, and doesn't lead you to what's really missing for it to become operational.

Comment: There's a detailed list of installs and setups for it to work at https://zacs-tech.com/how-to-install-qemu-kvm-and-virt-manager-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts/, but I can't say I got it working by following it myself, it still doesn't work for me.